# Can i use INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false in next.js?

Tags: webpack, next.js, build

I want to use `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false` in next.js
However, the runtime code is still shown in my new entry point js file?
Does it only work in react.js?

I already added `config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false` in next.config.js